# Excel formula value is between max and min limit with defined available steps

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Someone who can help me with a formula that checks if a value is between max and min value with defined available steps?
Example: Available values are given as
A1 =  1 (min limit) 
B1 = 2 (max limit)
C1 = 0.2 (available steps) 
Meaning that available values will be: 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8 and 2. Likewise the value 1.1 is not valid. 
The formula should return “Err” if value in A2 is not according to limits and available steps. The formula 
=IF(OR(A2B1);"Err";”ok”), handles min and max -limits but not available steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use IF(SUMPRODUCT())

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A1+C1*(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,INT((B1-A1)/C1)+1))-1)=A2)),"OK","ERR")
```

`(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,INT((B1-A1)/C1)+1))-1` creates an array of number from 0 to the number of times the steps needed to get to the upper limit.

That array is then passed to the math: `A1+C1*...=A2` and an Array of TRUE/FALSE is created.  SUMPRODUCT counts the TRUEs and if any, in this case it is either 1 or 0, The If will return TRUE.

[image]
[image]

---

Using Dynamic Arrays(only available in Office 365) we can shorten this:

```
=IF(OR(SEQUENCE((B1-A1)/C1+1,,A1,C1)=A2),"OK","ERR")
```

---

Edit, to avoid the array of steps:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A2>=A1,A2<=B1,MOD(ROUND((A2-A1)/C1,10),1)=0),"OK","Err"),"Nb! Check ""Step"" input")
```

[image]

Comment: Run into a couple of issues:some issues with limitation of possible number of steps.

Comment: See edit @LeifBottolfs

Comment: Your last formula did the trick!  I ran into a mysterious error in my formula.

Answer (score 0):

Run into a couple of issues with the "=IF(SUMPRODUCT" -formula... 
1) in the formula there is a limit of number of possible steps 
2) I prefer to avoid the use of $, since the formula is wildly copied to different workbooks.

I figured out a different formula (the part in front of "Iferror" handles cases where steps are not defined):

=IF(C1="";IF(AND(A2>=MIN(A1:B1);A2<=MAX(A1:B1));"ok";"Err");IFERROR(IF(AND(INT((A2-A1)/C1)=(A2-A1)/C1=TRUE;(A2-A1)/C1<=(B1-A1)/C1;(A2-A1)/C1>=0);"ok";"Err");"Nb! Check ""Step"" input"))

'Note! for some reason the formula produces an error that I can't really understand. In the formulas below I would expect the INT-formulas in cell A6 and A10 to equal 5. 
 [image: INT-formula-error]